# Computing pixel coordinate of a 3d point

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glm-math

I'm trying to compute the pixel coordinates of a 3d point (call this p) in world space. I understand I have to transform p from world space into camera space by multiplying it by the inverse of the camera-to-world matrix. Then find the coords of the point on the canvas using perspective projection, then convert this to pixel coordinates. I think this is correct?

I am currently stuck on finding the 4x4 matrix that would allow me to convert p from world space to camera space. If I have the vectors of my camera position and direction, how can I calculate this 4x4 matrix?

```
vec3 cameraPos = vec3(0.f, 0.f, -5.f);
vec3 cameraDir = vec3(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
```

Do I also need a camera up vector and what does this represent?

I am using glm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am currently stuck on finding the 4x4 matrix that would allow me to convert p from world space to camera space.

That matrix is called the view matrix. The view matrix is the [Inverse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) of that matrix, which is defined by the camera position and orientation (point of view).
The position is 3D point (`cameraPos`). The orientation of the camera is defined by the line of sight (`cameraDir`) and the up-vector. You have to define the up-vector, e.g. (0, 1, 0).

The [OpenGL Mathematics (GLM)](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html) library provides a handy function ([`glm::lookAt`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00247.html#gaa64aa951a0e99136bba9008d2b59c78e)), to compute the view matrix by the position, target and up-vector:

```cpp
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
```

```cpp
glm::vec3 cameraPos = glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, -5.f);
glm::vec3 cameraDir = glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
glm::vec3 cameraUp = glm::vec3(0.f, 1.f, 0.f);

glm::mat4 viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(cameraPos, cameraPos+cameraDir, cameraUp);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Appreciate it.